# How to access to a location in terminal through external link in org file?

Tags: org-mode, hyperlinks

I use org-mode and I often copy-paste path in a note file. Is it possible to have link or similar so it open a new terminal and go directly in the location indicated by the path.

I don't know much about elisp, but will be happy to learn a bit from this (maybe not so simple) exemple.

Thanks !

Comment: Is it important that the file be opened in a *new terminal*? [File links](https://orgmode.org/manual/External-Links.html#External-Links) open the file in Emacs itself - is that not acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2016/11/04/New-link-features-in-org-9/) on how to extend org links. Depending on the OS you are on, you'll need to figure out how to open a file / dir link in a terminal. On OSX, for example, you can do a 'open -a Terminal $HOME/Documents'.